# How can I calculate Precision and Recall for sentiment analysis multi-class classifier using Confusion Matrix?

Tags: classification, sentiment-analysis

I wonder how to compute precision and recall using a confusion matrix  sentiment analysis multi-class classifier using Confusion Matrix. I have a dataset of 5000 texts and I did human labeling for a sample of 100. Now, I would like to compute the Precision and Recall for the classifier based on this sample of data. I have three classes; Positive, Neutral and Negative.

**So how can I compute these metrics for each class?**

As I am new here in stackoverflow, I couldn't illustrate the confusion matrix I have, so let us assume that we have the following confusion matrix:

```
red color   > Negative
green color > Positive
purple color> Neutral
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can measure

**precision**=TPos/(TPos+TNeg+TNeu)  i.e 30/(30+20+10)=50% ,

**recall**=TPos/(TPos+FNeg+FNeu) i.e 30/(30+50+20)=30% ,

**F-measure**=2*precision*recall/(precision+recall)=37.5% ,and

**Accuracy**(all true)/(all data) =30+60+80/300=56.7% .

for more http://blog.kaggle.com/2015/10/23/scikit-learn-video-9-better-evaluation-of-classification-models/

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn's [classification report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).